# Three column CSS with dynamic automatic middle column by content and with same side columns

Tags: css

I was looking on internet for something like this for four days:

You have three column CSS, where middle column has automatic width according to content, where my content is one link with table below this link. Problem is, that I don't know table's width.

My first try was from this page: [Center Tables](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/centertables/)

This is pretty good (it centers table to the middle), but I want to have link to be above left top corner of this table. Problem is, that my link is always above center of table (not in left top corner). I tried to set margin to relative position of table, but it is not possible (correct me if I'm wrong).

So now I'm looking for solution, where I have three columns. The middle one shoud be automatically sized to content (to my table) and remaining width should be divided into two same side columns. Problem is, that I found a lot of tutorials, where they do three column sizing, but they always put width of middle column in pixels or in percent - but how can I know, what width will be needed.

I am thankful for every solution (using CSS or javascript).

Thanks

Comment: I think i understand your question, but would it not be inconsistent if the content is wider than screen..? May be you can post some code for better understanding to help you.

Comment: Can you post the code that you already have?